# Can I have multiple AdSense accounts?

Tags: google-adsense

Is it possible for me to have more than one AdSense account, or would that violate Google's terms of service in some way?

Comment: If you mean, multiple adsense accounts then the answer is no.  You use one adsense account for all of your properties (sites)

Comment: You should make that answer so you can get up votes and be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat What did do to question? :)

Comment: @abel you can see by clicking "X mins ago" above my usename, it takes you to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/5127/revisions . I just cleaned up the title into better English :)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I wanted you to edit the body too,to "Can I have multiple Adsense accounts?"

Answer (score 5):

From Google AdSense FAQ: [Can I sign up for more than one account?](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9729)

> No. Publishers are not permitted to
>   maintain multiple AdSense accounts
>   under the same payee name.
>
> However, we've provided some guidance
>   below that may help you if you're
>   trying to submit multiple
>   applications. Please identify which
>   common reason best describes your
>   situation, then follow the
>   instructions below.

Answer (score 3):

After going through the [original source of the question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/revisions/baba2e47-24b3-4635-8cbb-0878d2d40f19/view-source), OP wanted to ask whether

> Can i will have adsense multiple
>   account **difference name and address**
>   but same surname ?

**Two different names** and **addresses** are essentially **two different people**, and a lot of people share surnames.

I may as well add that two siblings may(?) be allowed to have two adsense accounts for different names but same address. So different names but same addresses may(?) also do.

But if you are impersonating someone else and are creating accounts under different names and address for your own use then it is not permissible.

Further Reading:

https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms

http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9729

Comment: Should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently researched on this topic. Accoding to my understanding, you can have multiple accounts if

1) The addresses are different

OR

2) Each account is a separate company / firm (even if they have same address).

(Thus you can have 1 individual + any number of company accounts at same address).

You cannot have multiple "individual" (non company) accounts at same address even for family members.

Do confirm all of this in google TOS though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. If address is different and other details like bank account are different you can access multiple accounts but you can't all accounts in website or blog.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   Good answers here are backed up with links to references or anecdotes from personal experience.   Please edit this answer to add to it.